# I have an error access to github (website)

Tags: github

I try to connect website github.com with chrome but I have an error.

```
      This site can’t be reached
      github.com took too long to respond.
      Try:
          Checking the connection
          Checking the proxy and the firewall
          Running Network Diagnostics
          ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I search google and try to change proxy and firewall. but not working!
I need to help. please!!!

Comment: Are you from china? Github might be blocked from china, not sure though.

Comment: @tkausl I would suspect Vietnam, with the name "nguyen".

Comment: Google searches that might be more helpful are "network timeout troubleshooting", or "traceroute". There's not a lot of information to go on in your current question, so including some more relevant information would be useful.

Comment: error from.... when i try pod install project but i have an error and its :
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
then I access url = 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' but it not working

Comment: I think it error from not connect to 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' .
yesterday I search error in there and try to fix it but not working.